# Underscored properties in Swift classes?

Tags: swift, memory, core-animation, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to do a few things that involve overriding methods in Apples's classes. More specifically, I'm trying to modifiy the animation that puts the cancel button of UISearchController on screen when the user clicks on the search bar. As it stands, my uisearchbar is in place of my navigation item's titleView.

However I have a UIBarButton on the right. When I click on the search bar. the cancel button slides in from the search bar's right edge, by the right bar button, and the right bar button item doesn't move. I would like the cancel button to slide in from screen's edge.

To this end, I've started looking at ways to subclass the search bar so that I could change the animation. While examining memory in the console, I've noticed that almost all variables start with an underscore (_cancelBarButtonItem) and what's more, none of them is accecssible.

My questions are then: what are those variables, can I access them somehow, and otherwise can I override them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. These are private variables that Apple uses in their classes (you can declare your own with the `private` keyword). It is just a convention to use an underscore before their name.
2. It is possible to access them using **Key-Value Coding** (KVC). In your case, to get the variable, you would do the following: `webView.valueForKey("_cancelBarButtonItem")`
3. If you want to set them, you can do this: `webView.setValue(value, forKey: "_cancelBarButtonItem")` where `value` is the value you want to set it to.

Note: Apple strongly discourages accessing their private variables, and doing so may get your app rejected